# Can't access link below another positioned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, swipe

I am trying to create a swipe event that will hide / show the navigation at the bottom of a mobile-ready page. The swipe needs to be at the bottom of the page, as if the user was swiping on the navigation itself.

I have a `<nav>` with the `<div class=swipearea>` above it, both are fixed to the bottom of the page, and the `.swipearea` is z-indexed to be above the nav. Of course, this makes the links in the navigation unclickable. I have tried making the `<nav>` swipeable, but this just drags the elements in the `<nav>` on my desktop test machine when I swipe down. If I put the event on the div.swipearea, the functionality works like a charm, but no links are clickable.

I need to be able to click a link and be able to swipe the navigation up or down. I suggested a small tab to pull down, but the client doesn't want to use that. They want the navigation hidden by default, swipe up and navigation appears, swipe down and it disappears.

Of course, I need the navigation links to work too.

example code:

```
<div class="swipearea"></div>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="somewhere.html">Link1</a</li>
        <li><a href="another.html">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="yetanother.html">Link3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```